# How can I translate "we are hundreds of kilometers apart"?

Tags: grammar, english-comparison, translation

I am trying to say

> I miss my mother everyday because we are hundreds of kilometres apart and I only get to talk to her on the internet.

Can I say this?

> Manco molto mia madre perché stiamo a centinaia di chilometri di distanza e solo posso parlare con lei su internet.

Comment: "mancare" is like "piacere", you have to invert subject and object:
"I like him" -> Lui mi piace (piace A ME)
"I miss my mother" -> Mia madre MI manca (manca a me)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sì, “stiamo [o siamo, o ci troviamo] a centinaia di chilometri di distanza” va benissimo. È nel resto che c'è qualche problema. Complessivamente, direi: «Mi manca molto mia madre perché siamo a centinaia di chilometri di distanza e posso parlare con lei [o “le posso parlare”] solo su internet».

Comment: So I have to use essere and not stare?

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta You can use both *stiamo* or *siamo* in this context.

Comment: @DanielOrtizCosta: Indeed, you can use any of them: I meant just this by “stiamo [o siamo, o ci troviamo]”. Somebody finds “stiamo” slightly more colloquial, but you'll get these nuances by reading and listening enough.